# How to generate one large dependency map for the whole project that builds with makefiles?

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I have a gigantic project that is built using makefiles. Running make at the root of the project takes over 20 minutes when no files have changed (i.e. just traversing the project and checking for updated files).

I'd like to create a dependency map that will tell me which directories I need to run 'make' in based on the file(s) changed. I already have a list of updated files that I can get from my version control system, and I'd like to skip the 20 minutes of traversing and get straight to the locations that do need to be recompiled.

The project has a mix of several languages and custom tools, so this would ideally be language-independent (i.e. it would only process all makefiles to generate dependencies). I'll settle for a C/C++-specific solution, too, as the majority of the project is in C++. The project is built on Linux.

[Edit - clarifications, responses to comments]

The project truly is gigantic, it's taking 20 minutes simply because of the size and because of all things described in the link below ("recursive makes consider harmful"). Unfortunately, the project is put together from many pieces coming from many different places, and there's little flexibility in what I can do with low-level Makefiles... the top-level ones putting the pieces together are the ones I have control over.

Comment: 20 minutes sounds long. How many files are there? And what method are you using now to generate the dependencies?

Comment: Have you read "Recursive Make Considered Harmful" and applied the ideas therein? Twenty minutes just to check things out seems to scream out that there are structural problems with the build.

Comment: Link: http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/

Comment: I was looking for a related task recently and found this: http://sailhome.cs.queensu.ca/~bram/makao/index.html

Comment: @rescdsk: That looks like an answer not a comment: if offers to do *exactly* what Stan has asked for.

Comment: It looks like a nifty tool, but maybe not *exactly* what Stan asked for. It's not clear to me that it can take a list of modified files and return a list of directories that need to be Made, and even if it can, it seems like too much tool for the job. (Although it might reveal the underlying clot that leads to a 20-minute build time.) I'll bet we can come up with a neat little script to do the job, and maybe find the cause too.

Comment: @rescdsk: this looks interesting, I'll have to take a closer look at it and see how it can be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could look for is "makefile graph" -- there are a few projects out there to make dependency trees from large makefile projects.  Here's one: http://sailhome.cs.queensu.ca/~bram/makao/index.html .  I think it will both create a pretty graph, and actually build things.

If you want to roll your own Makefile parser, and essentially replace make with your own custom script, my advice would be "don't".  But there is a collection of Perl modules:  [Makefile::Parser](http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/dist/Makefile-Parser).  It claims to "pass 51% of the GNU Make test suite".

If you want to just look at what's taking so long, you can turn on Make's debugging output.  Bits of it are usually sort of useless, like the pages and pages of Make deciding whether or not to apply implicit rules, but maybe there will be some obvious thing that happens that doesn't need to happen.  If you want to do this, you could look at [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/), "GNU Make with comprehensible tracing and a debugger".

Answer (score 0):

If a simple make with no updates takes 20 minutes, that must be a huge project! Considering that your makefile configuration is OK you could try something like [ccache](http://ccache.samba.org/).

notice that even if you get the list of files you just need to comiple, you might still need to run make from the root of the project because the changes will have to be linked back into the main binaries. So if ccache is not good enough yet, and you insist in solving that problem yourself, you will still have to track which binary files you have to re-link again with "ld"

Comment: ccache helps with unnecessary recompilatons. Although it solves that particular problem in an occasional subtree, it doesn't help to traverse the project quickly. In fact, it adds about 2-3 minutes to "no files changed" make :(.